# How to get rid of VSCode indentation indicators?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So this might be a bit of a stupid question, but I can't figure this out. I have these indentation indicators (arrows for tabs, dots for space based indentation) however I'm trying to figure out how to disable them. Images of what I mean are included below.

[image: Indentation - Tabs]

[image: Indentation - Spaces]

This is an example of what I want it to look like and it is what it looks like for other team members

[image: Example of what I want to achieve]

Comment: Looks like the setting is named `renderWhitespace`.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: That was it, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Take a screenshot of you changing it, and you can write the answer to your own question

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to Ben Voigt in comments

Option I was looking for was "Render Whitespace" and setting it to 'none'.

[image]